# Plone portal_transform not running in new content created via webdav

Tags: plone, plone-4.x

Using Plone 4.3.4, I have created file system products to create a new Dexterity content type ("Article") and a new Transform. Article contains a RichTextField and a custom transform ("xml_to_html").

The xml_to_html transform is designed to convert the raw XML input of the RichTextField into HTML output using a SAX-based parser and templating system. *This works perfectly when creating or modifying Article items through the web.*

The mime_types_registry is set to map Article to *.xml and mimetype text/xml.

When uploading an XML file via WebDav, Plone correctly creates an Article with the RichTextField designated as primary. However, the xml_to_html transform does not run to create the transformed output. RichTextValue.raw contains the uploaded file content, but RichTextValue.output is never generated.

A further complication is that the WebDav client is setting Content-Type: text/xml but the RichTextValue.mimeType is always coming through as text/plain.

I can see that my type-specific event hooks are working. I can execute arbitrary code based on zope.lifecycleevent.interfaces.IObjectAddedEvent, but the object creation process never hits the xml_to_html transform.

Questions:
a) Are portal_transforms applied to content items created via WebDav? If not, then that's my answer.

b) Why is the mimetype of the primary field not respecting the value set by the webdav client?

Thanks,
Don

Answer (score 0):

### Content Type

The mimeType and encoding properties are sets on the value of the Content-Type header - [docs.plone.org](http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/serving/webdav.html#put)

Checkout your webdav client content-type headers.

The Content-Type request header MUST be set appropriately for an XML body (e.g., set to "text/xml" or "application/xml").

### Second case

New Article Item object creates with 'text/plain' by default.

In this case you can call

```
context.portal_transforms.convert('xml_to_html',context.richtextfield_name)
```

directly in article-template-view.pt and other content specific views.

Comment: I am examining and manipulating Content-Type headers with Charles Proxy. I have the content_types_registry set correctly and the correct content types are being created. The dilemma is that the portal_transform doesn't run until I do a TTW edit. When I examine the RichTextValue during content creation, the mimetype doesn't match the value set in the webdav PUT request. I've decided to just sidestep the whole thing and relay on the content added and content modified events to do my processing. Portal_Transform is inefficient because the results are only cached and not stored persistently.